# Fast extraction of chunks of lines from large CSV file

Tags: python, performance, csv

I have a large CSV file full of stock-related data formatted as such:

> Ticker Symbol, Date, [some variables...]

So each line starts of with the symbol (like "AMZN"), then has the date, then has 12 variables related to price or volume on the selected date.  There are about 10,000 different securities represented in this file and I have a line for each day that the stock has been publicly traded for each of them.  The file is ordered first alphabetically by ticker symbol and second chronologically by date.  The entire file is about 3.3 GB.

The sort of task I want to solve would be to be able to extract the most recent *n* lines of data for a given ticker symbol with respect to the current date.  I have code that does this, but based on my observations it seems to take, on average, around 8-10 seconds per retrieval (all tests have been extracting 100 lines).

I have functions I'd like to run that require me to grab such chunks for hundreds or thousands of symbols, and I would really like to reduce the time.  My code is inefficient, but I am not sure how to make it run faster.

First, I have a function called getData:

```
def getData(symbol, filename):
  out = ["Symbol","Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Dividend",
         "Split","Adj_Open","Adj_High","Adj_Low","Adj_Close","Adj_Volume"]
  l = len(symbol)
  beforeMatch = True
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = checkMatch(symbol, l, line)
        if beforeMatch and match:
            beforeMatch = False
            out.append(formatLineData(line[:-1].split(",")))
        elif not beforeMatch and match:
            out.append(formatLineData(line[:-1].split(",")))
        elif not beforeMatch and not match:
            break
  return out
```

(This code has a couple of helper functions, checkMatch and formatLineData, which I will show below.)  Then, there is another function called getDataColumn that gets the column I want with the correct number of days represented:

```
def getDataColumn(symbol, col=12, numDays=100, changeRateTransform=False):
  dataset = getData(symbol)
  if not changeRateTransform:
    column = [day[col] for day in dataset[-numDays:]]
  else:
    n = len(dataset)
    column = [(dataset[i][col] - dataset[i-1][col])/dataset[i-1][col] for i in range(n - numDays, n)]
  return column
```

(changeRateTransform converts raw numbers into daily change rate numbers if True.)  The helper functions:

```
def checkMatch(symbol, symbolLength, line):
  out = False
  if line[:symbolLength+1] == symbol + ",":
    out = True
  return out

def formatLineData(lineData):
  out = [lineData[0]]
  out.append(datetime.strptime(lineData[1], '%Y-%m-%d').date())
  out += [float(d) for d in lineData[2:6]]
  out += [int(float(d)) for d in lineData[6:9]]
  out += [float(d) for d in lineData[9:13]]
  out.append(int(float(lineData[13])))
  return out
```

Does anyone have any insight on what parts of my code run slow and how I can make this perform better?  I can't do the sort of analysis I want to do without speeding this up.

---

EDIT:
In response to the comments, I made some changes to the code in order to utilize the existing methods in the csv module:

```
def getData(symbol, database):
  out = ["Symbol","Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Dividend",
         "Split","Adj_Open","Adj_High","Adj_Low","Adj_Close","Adj_Volume"]
  l = len(symbol)
  beforeMatch = True
  with open(database, 'r') as f:
    databaseReader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in databaseReader:
        match = (row[0] == symbol)
        if beforeMatch and match:
            beforeMatch = False
            out.append(formatLineData(row))
        elif not beforeMatch and match:
            out.append(formatLineData(row))
        elif not beforeMatch and not match:
            break
  return out

def getDataColumn(dataset, col=12, numDays=100, changeRateTransform=False):
  if not changeRateTransform:
    out = [day[col] for day in dataset[-numDays:]]
  else:
    n = len(dataset)
    out = [(dataset[i][col] - dataset[i-1][col])/dataset[i-1][col] for i in range(n - numDays, n)]
  return out
```

Performance was worse using the csv.reader class.  I tested on two stocks, AMZN (near top of file) and ZNGA (near bottom of file).  With the original method, the run times were 0.99 seconds and 18.37 seconds, respectively.  With the new method leveraging the csv module, the run times were 3.04 seconds and 64.94 seconds, respectively.  Both return the correct results.

My thought is that the time is being taken up more from finding the stock than from the parsing.  If I try these methods on the first stock in the file, A, the methods both run in about 0.12 seconds.

Comment: You should use the csv module rather than rolling your own here. The pandas csv reader can also substantially speed up ingestion.

Comment: A further option, for repeated queries, is to throw the whole thing into sqlite and add some indices.

Comment: you may consider using a generator by replacing all the `out.append(...)` with `yield ...` so that the function can execute lazily (less reallocating space for the ever growing list)

Comment: wait a moment... `getData` process the entire file into a massive list so that `getDataColumn` can use just a single column? Are you then running `getDataColumn` multiple times to process each column... just take the processed data as an argument to `getDataColumn` so you only have to do the file processing once!

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen that is a fair point, although I haven't been encountering slow downs due to repeated getData calls because I've only been working with one column thus far.  But I will use the others eventually so I can make that change.  And I will look into using generators.

Comment: @JeffDavis the whole rolling your own bad csv parser and mixing it up with your data manipulation is just a bad idea and a terrific opportunity to introduce complexity, fragility and poor performance characteristics. Just don't do it. Use the provided tools.

Comment: @pvg I agree that using the csv module is a really good idea but I think you may have been harsh in that last comment

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen i'm not really seeing it. If you whip up a quick ad-hoc csv parser it will probably be bad and perform poorly compared to one that's had years of refinement. I know it would be if I did it, for sure.

Comment: I'd write it all to a DB then query that for the desired output.

Comment: One problem with this question is that whatever is going to make finding all lines for one particular symbol fast (i.e. not doing any work for all other symbols), will not help you much in the grand picture of things, when you will be interested in many more.

Comment: Can you gzip and toss that file up somewhere or a part of it?

Comment: Is the chronological order newest first or oldest first? What other regularities does the file have? Are all lines for the same ticker of exactly the same length? Do all tickers have the exact same number of lines?

Comment: @ThijsvanDien By chronologically, I mean newest first.  All lines are exactly the same length.  For each symbol that's in the data, I have a record for every day that the symbol has been publicly traded, so each ticker has a different number of lines.  Another thing to remember is that the first ordering is alphabetical, so once we find the symbol for which we are searching we will have found a contiguous segment of data that contains _all_ of the records for that symbol in the entire data set.

Comment: @pvg I cannot share the file, it is proprietary.

Comment: @JeffDavis yeah that makes it a little tricky to narrow down specific performance issues. But i think we've identified a couple of different areas. One is speed of ingestion - I think pandas covers this very well. Another is speed of processing which again might be covered by pandas if your dataset is an in-memory one. And lastly, is this about a static dataset or one that has continuous updates.

Comment: @pvg This is a dataset that will have a small amount of data coming in each trading day

Comment: @JeffDavis I think the right answer here is 'put it in a sql db'. This is less code than everything written or suggested so far, deals with the bulk of the issues by default and lets your focus on whatever analysis you have in mind. We're thinking about optimizing something like 'putting your pants on' while the actual goal is closer to 'going outside and mowing the lawn'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're going to do lots of analysis on the same dataset, the pragmatic approach would be to read it all into a database. It is made for fast querying; CSV isn't. Use the sqlite command line tools, for example, which can directly import from CSV. Then add a single index on `(Symbol, Date)` and lookups will be practically instantaneous.

If for some reason that is not feasible, for example because new files can come in at any moment and you cannot afford the preparation time before starting your analysis of them, you'll have to make the best of dealing with CSV directly, which is what the rest of my answer will focus on. Remember that it's a balancing act, though. Either you pay a lot upfront, or a bit extra for every lookup. Eventually, for some amount of lookups it would have been cheaper to pay upfront.

Optimization is about maximizing the amount of work not done. Using generators and the built-in `csv` module aren't going to help much with that in this case. You'd still be reading the whole file and parsing all of it, at least for line breaks. With that amount of data, it's a no-go.

Parsing requires reading, so you'll have to find a way around it first. Best practices of leaving all intricacies of the CSV format to the specialized module bear no meaning when they can't give you the performance you want. Some cheating must be done, but as little as possible. In this case, I suppose it is safe to assume that the start of a new line can be identified as `b'\n"AMZN",'` (sticking with your example). Yes, binary here, because remember: no parsing yet. You could scan the file *as binary* from the beginning until you find the first line. From there read the amount of lines you need, decode and parse them the proper way, etc. No need for optimization there, because a 100 lines are nothing to worry about compared to the hundreds of thousands of irrelevant lines you're not doing that work for.

Dropping all that parsing buys you a lot, but the reading needs to be optimized as well. Don't load the whole file into memory first and skip as many layers of Python as you can. Using `mmap` lets the OS decide what to load into memory transparently and lets you work with the data directly.

Still you're potentially reading the whole file, if the symbol is near the end. It's a linear search, which means the time it takes is linearly proportional to the number of lines in the file. You can do better though. Because the file is sorted, you could improve the function to instead perform a kind of binary search. The number of steps that will take (where a step is reading a line) is close to the binary logarithm of the number of lines. In other words: the number of times you can divide your file into two (almost) equally sized parts. When there are one million lines, that's a difference of five orders of magnitude!

Here's what I came up with, based on Python's own `bisect_left` with some measures to account for the fact that your "values" span more than one index:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice
import mmap

def iter_symbol_lines(f, symbol):
    # How to recognize the start of a line of interest
    ident = b'"' + symbol.encode() + b'",'
    # The memory-mapped file
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    # Skip the header
    mm.readline()
    # The inclusive lower bound of the byte range we're still interested in
    lo = mm.tell()
    # The exclusive upper bound of the byte range we're still interested in
    hi = mm.size()
    # As long as the range isn't empty
    while lo < hi:
        # Find the position of the beginning of a line near the middle of the range
        mid = mm.rfind(b'\n', 0, (lo+hi)//2) + 1
        # Go to that position
        mm.seek(mid)
        # Is it a line that comes before lines we're interested in?
        if mm.readline() < ident:
            # If so, ignore everything up to right after this line
            lo = mm.tell()
        else:
            # Otherwise, ignore everything from right before this line
            hi = mid
    # We found where the first line of interest would be expected; go there
    mm.seek(lo)
    while True:
        line = mm.readline()
        if not line.startswith(ident):
            break
        yield line.decode()

with open(filename) as f:
    r = csv.reader(islice(iter_symbol_lines(f, 'AMZN'), 10))
    for line in r:
        print(line)
```

No guarantees about this code; I didn't pay much attention to edge cases, and I couldn't test with (any of) your file(s), so consider it a proof of concept. It is plenty fast, however – think tens of milliseconds on an SSD!

Comment: Since you're making the effort of going through all the options - `pandas.read_table` is very fast (assuming options that allow for `engine='c'` and a decently sized `chunksize`)

Comment: @pvg I actually tried `pandas` with a 3,5GB file and couldn't really get it to behave well (i.e. not sucking up all my memory, even when chunked).

Comment: That's odd. I get a pretty consistent 2x and up improvement on ingestion from it. I don't think ingestion is the fundamental issue here but it seems strange we got such divergent numbers.

Comment: @pvg Sure there must be some way to resolve that, but I'm not sure what it would add to my answer. It mostly focusses on making CSV work well enough and I think it now does. :)

Comment: Yep, you're right and I'm becoming increasingly convinced (from the poster's comments) this is not really a question about ingestion.

Comment: Wow, this method in the edit is excellent!  It is blazing fast and it seems to work based on a few quick tests I ran.  I will definitely spend more time digging into this code and understanding it point-by-point.  I should mention that I have at this point successfully set up a SQLite DB and imported the CSV with the composite primary key, and it retrieves query results virtually instantaneously like you said, but I really appreciate you posting this for me as it is a great learning tool for me and also a great backup in case the SQLite approach ever becomes infeasible for any reason.

Comment: @JeffDavis Good to hear. Please note that for a few minutes my answer contained a mistake, so if you're going to try the bisect method more, make sure you're using the correct version.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien I have the correct version - it is working for me and it matches what you have up now.

Answer (score 2):

So I have an alternative solution which I ran and tested on my own as well with a sample data set that I got on Quandl that appears to have all the same headers and similar data. (Assuming that I havent misunderstood the end result that your trying to achieve).

I have this command line tool that one of our engineers built for us for parsing massive csvs - since I deal with absurd amount of data on a day to day basis - it is open sourced and you can get it here: https://github.com/DataFoxCo/gocsv

I also already wrote the short bash script for it in case you don't want to pipeline the commands but it does also support pipelining.

**The command to run the following short script follows a super simple convention:**

`bash tickers.sh wikiprices.csv 'AMZN' '2016-12-\d+|2016-11-\d+'`

```
#!/bin/bash


dates="$3"
cat "$1" \
  | gocsv filter --columns 'ticker' --regex "$2" \
  | gocsv filter --columns 'date' --regex "$dates" > "$2"'-out.csv'
```

- both arguments for ticker and for dates are regexes
- You can add as many variations as your want into that one regex, separating them by `|`.
- So if you wanted AMZN and MSFT then you would simply modify it to this: `AMZN|MSFT`
- I did something very similar with the dates - but i only limited my sample run to any dates from this month or last month.

**End Result**

Starting data:

```
myusername$ gocsv dims wikiprices.csv    
Dimensions:
  Rows: 23946
  Columns: 14

myusername$ bash tickers.sh wikiprices.csv 'AMZN|MSFT' '2016-12-\d+'

myusername$ gocsv dims AMZN|MSFT-out.csv
Dimensions:
  Rows: 24
  Columns: 14
```

Here is a sample where I limited to only those 2 tickers and then to december only:

[image]

Voila - in a matter of seconds you have a second file saved with out the data you care about.

The gocsv program has great documentation by the way - and a ton of other functions e.g. running a vlookup basically at any scale (which is what inspired the creator to make the tool)

Comment: Thank you so much - this looks excellent. I will be sure to study up on gocsv. And you are right, this is Quandl data.

Comment: ;) They don't call me a data ninja for nothing haha

Comment: Also feel free to hit me up if you have any questions etc - esp since gocsv came from our repo - aurielle at datafox.co

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do that!

Answer (score 1):

in addition to using `csv.reader` I think using `itertools.groupby` would speed up looking for the wanted sections, so the actual iteration could look something like this:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby 
from operator import itemgetter #for the keyfunc for groupby

def getData(wanted_symbol, filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        #so each line in reader is basically line[:-1].split(",") from the plain file
        for symb, lines in groupby(reader, itemgetter(0)):
            #so here symb is the symbol at the start of each line of lines
            #and lines is the lines that all have that symbol in common
            if symb != wanted_symbol:
                continue #skip this whole section if it has a different symbol
            for line in lines:
                #here we have each line as a list of fields
                #for only the lines that have `wanted_symbol` as the first element
                <DO STUFF HERE>
```

so in the space of `<DO STUFF HERE>` you could have the `out.append(formatLineData(line))` to do what your current code does but the code for that function has a lot of unnecessary slicing and `+=` operators which I think are pretty expensive for lists (might be wrong), another way you could apply the conversions is to have a list of all the conversions:

```
def conv_date(date_str):
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

#the conversions applied to each element (taken from original formatLineData)
castings = [str, conv_date,             #0, 1
            float, float, float, float, #2:6
            int, int, int,              #6:9
            float, float, float, float, #9:13
            int]                        #13
```

then use `zip` to apply these to each field in a line in a list comprehension:

```
 [conv(val) for conv, val in zip(castings, line)]
```

so you would replace `<DO STUFF HERE>` with `out.append` with that comprehension.

---

I'd also wonder if switching the order of `groupby` and `reader` would be better since you don't need to parse most of the file as csv, just the parts you are actually iterating over so you could use a keyfunc that seperates just the first field of the string

```
def getData(wanted_symbol, filename):
    out = [] #why are you starting this with strings in it?
    def checkMatch(line): #define the function to only take the line
        #this would be the keyfunc for groupby in this example
        return line.split(",",1)[0] #only split once, return the first element

    with open(filename) as file:
        for symb, lines in groupby(file,checkMatch):
            #so here symb is the symbol at the start of each line of lines
            if symb != wanted_symbol:
                continue #skip this whole section if it has a different symbol
            for line in csv.reader(lines):
                out.append(  [typ(val) for typ,val in zip(castings,line)]  )
    return out
```

Comment: Thank you for the post, but this code does not reduce my run time.  The edited version runs faster, but it still takes ~42 seconds for AMZN and ~47 seconds for ZNGA.  I do appreciate this post for showing me how to use groupby, itemgetter, and zip, which I have not used before.

Comment: ok so that confirms that most of the time is taken finding the sections, I'd wonder if finding the first occurence with something like `whole_file = f.reead() ; start_i = whole_file.index(symbol)` then starting the parsing from `start_i` by slicing would yield better results, of course this requires storing the whole file or large chunks of the file in memory, if that doesn't speed up processing then I think the issue may just be that your hard-drive is slow...

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen you can `mmap` the thing and see if it makes a difference. But I think the fundamental issue is the whole thing is non-reproducible which leaves few good options outside of guessing.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I am definitely not using a very high-performance machine, so the hard drive might be a constraint.  How can I make a determination about whether my machine can handle bringing the whole file into memory?

Comment: um... I'd assume if you have at least the size of the file in RAM you'd be able to load it all into memory, still loading a whole 3.3GB file into memory isn't recommended even if possible, pvg's suggestion of using `mmap` would definitely be better then loading the whole thing. (lets you treat the file like a string directly)

Comment: The real problem here is the algorithm. Whether you use `str.index`, `itertools.groupby`, or whichever other mechanism to process lines, something is going to read all those lines, even if you hide it. Reading 3GB worth of data and throwing away over 99.99% is never going to be fast. For it to be fast, you need to drastically reduce what is going to be even read, which is possible if the file is sorted as has been stated.